# Xamarin Android binding results in interfaces and no classes

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, ultralite

I am binding a 3rd party JAR file for my Xamarin Android project.  It binds with no errors but quite a few warnings about "hiding" (CS0108) and "not hiding" (CS0109) accessible members.

When I code in the Android project, the classes I expect aren't there but corresponding interfaces are.  This is making the use of this library difficult, as I reference their help system and samples.

Can anyone answer as to why this occurs, interfaces en lieu of classes?  Can I use the `MetaData.xml` file to prevent this?  If so, it would be great to have an example, as I find the various entries none too intuitive.

The JAR is bound as an Embedded JAR.  I have used both "Android Class Parsers" and "Codegen Targets" in all permutations possible in VS2017.  It is being compiled for the same "Target Framework" as the Android Project.

This JAR is for UltraLite db accessing.

Answer (score 0):

I continued to debug this issue and I decompiled the JAR.  Result is that all the objects I was expecting as a Class are defined in the JAR file as an interface.  SAP UltraLite support let me down on this one.  But then they said this JAR is intended for and works in Android Studio.  It has not been vetted for Xamarin.